# itextsharp add a table row from javascript

Tags: itext

How to add a new table row from JavaScript using iTextSharp in the editable PDF?  Please advise, below is the code which I've tried to add a new table row from javascript,

```
/* to register the javascript to call when the button on click*/
field.Action = PdfAction.JavaScript("this.jsAddRow('" + table + "')", writer);
```

Below is the Javascript function,

```
function jsAddRow(objTable) {
    /* Add a new row*/
    objTable.Row1.instanceManager.addInstance();
}
```

Comment: As soon as the table is in the pdf, it's not a table anymore but instead a collection of lines and text pieces. Our do you by chance mean an xfa structure?

Comment: The OP mentions that he's working with an *editable PDF*, so it may be an XFA form. The OP should clarify, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is wrong and you didn't do any effort to clarify or to correct your question. You shouldn't expect an answer if you can't phrase the question correctly! Nevertheless, I'll try to take a look in my crystal ball and find an answer anyway.

You say you have an editable PDF, which leads to believe that you have a PDF form. You are not telling us whether

- you have a form based on AcroForm technology, or
- a form based on the XML Forms Architecture (XFA).

Based on your code, one would guess that you have an AcroForm. You create an action dictionary and you want to add this action to a field dictionary. These are PDF objects and that is how AcroForm forms are constructed.

However, you say that you want to add a row, which is impossible in the context in AcroForms, this is only possible in the context of XFA. As XFA forms are constructed using XML, it is obvious that your attempt to add an action dictionary to a field dictionary doesn't work. You should manipulate the XML instead!

Do you understand why people are confused when they read your question? There is a contradiction in your question and you didn't do any effort to clarify, not on StackOverflow, not to the sales people at iText Software.

Please take a look at the [`FillXFA`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xfa/FillXFA) example. This example has a form ([purchase_order.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/purchase_order.pdf)) that contains a dynamic table:

[image]

When you click on the "Add Item" button, more rows are added. This is done through JavaScript that is added by the person who created the PDF in Adobe LiveCycle Designer. **You can not add this JavaScript as an Action dictionary the way you would add JavaScript to an AcroForm field!!!** This button is defined using XML and the JavaScript is part of the XML! If you want to create such a form, you need a tool such as Adobe LiveCycle Designer to create a dynamic form. **By design, AcroForm forms can never be dynamic!!!**

Now suppose that you have a form that has a button saying "Add Item" or "Add Row", how do you trigger that using iText? Well, **you don't!** Those buttons are meant to be pressed by humans. You can add rows using iText by adding data! For instance: if we add [data.xml](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/data.xml), which is a set of data in the form of an XML file, we get this result: [purchase_order_filled.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/purchase_order_filled.pdf)

[image]

As you can see, the data present in the XML file was added, as well as a number of empty rows (which correspond with empty data rows in the XML). As we added many rows, we even triggered a new page to be added to the PDF.

This is how it's done:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,
            new FileOutputStream(dest));
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    XfaForm xfa = form.getXfa();
    xfa.fillXfaForm(new FileInputStream(XML));
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

**You do not need JavaScript**, nor an "Add Item" or "Add Row" button to do this. It's just a matter of adding the right data. This is shown in the [`XfaMovies`](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=165) example from the web site: [xfa_movies.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/resources/pdfs/xfa_movies.pdf) is a single page PDF without any buttons. We inject the data of 120 movies: [movies.xml](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter08/movies.xml). The result is the 23-page PDF, [xfa_filled_in.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter08/xfa_filled_in.pdf).

Once again, in case you didn't listen well: this is only possible when using XFA technology. This is **NOT** possible using AcroForm technology!!!